# Is it any way to store Dbgprint () messages to a file?

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver

I want to store `DbgprintEx()` or `Dbgprint()` kernel messages to a external file like `C:\file.txt` . Is it any way to store this messages . Because i want to analyze the kernel messages before crash . i also checked `Kernel debugging` using `winDbg` but my application can't connect on debug mode . I am using windows 7 64 bit Machine .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grab those logs with DebugView from sysinternals - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx, as I checked it allows to save logs to file.

Comment: But when i got crash , this messages will be disappear ? i want to see this logs after OS crash  . can I ? or is it any setup for automatically store logs from Dbgview to a file ?

Comment: what is Log-to-file scenario in Dbgview ? Is it automatically copy all the logs to a file ?

Answer (score 0):

try command:
.logopen /t c:\logs\mylogfile.txt

Any output will be save in log file, not only debug output. But maybe it fits for you?